# Checking column condition based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a training database and the first table(employee table) has employee id(Int), isTrainer(Bool)..etc. And the second table(training record) has trainee id(Int), trainer id(Int)..etc. Trainee id and trainer id is reference to employee id. But trainer id should only be employee that isTrainer(Bool = true). How do I achieve that?

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA training;
go

CREATE TABLE training.employee(
    employee_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    employee_isTrainer BOOLEAN;
);

CREATE TABLE training.record(
    training_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    training_trainee INT NOT NULL;
    training_trainer INT NOT NULL;
    FOREIGN KEY (training_trainee) REFERENCES training.employee(employee_id);
    FOREIGN KEY (training_trainer) REFERENCES training.employee(employee_id);
)
```

I am creating a front end with a drop down for user to query or add new record. The expected outcome should be the trainer dropdown should only show employee that isTrainer.

Comment: Add a constraint?

Comment: I cannot think of any idea other than a Trigger.

Comment: Add an isTrainer column to the training.record table. FK both columns.